# Check DLL for Windows API Level

Tags: windows, api, dll

Is there a tool that can check a DLL against a specific API Level? We have run into problems with a DLL from an external Developer that does not work under Windows 2000 and now we are trying to find all Windows API calls that do not exist in Win2k.

Is there something like that?

Comment: Best to just debug your solution in a Win2k VM perhaps?

Comment: Why are you trying to run anything in Win2k?  It's been out of support for over 18 months.  Nobody should be using it for anything any more.

Comment: Because some of our users still use Win2k and want to use our software. I am afraid that taking it out of support did not automatically upgrade all PCs out there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how it works.  You have to specify what OS support you require when you *build* the DLL.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500  // supporting Windows 2000
#include <windows.h>
// etc...
```

You'll get a compile error when you try to use an api function that isn't available.

Comment: That's true, but you get a runtime error when you set `_WIN32_WINNT` to `0x0501`, use an XP only function and then deploy the DLL on W2K.

Comment: That's true, that's why you have to set it to 0x500 :)

Comment: Well, that's a good point. Ask the external developer to do that and let the compiler do the work. Much easier than frabbing around with depends.exe.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint with #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500. As I have acces to the source, I have just tried that. Unfortunately, I do not get an error there, though I know, that there is at least one unsupported function (EnterCriticalSection). I made sure that it is placed above the windows.h include. I also have tried setting it in any places where windows.h was included, to make sure it will be considered. Do you have an idea why that cold be?

Comment: EnterCriticalSection is on w2k.

Comment: If you have trouble with EnterCriticalSection then odds are high that you are actually having a threading bug in the code.  This falls in the category of *hard bugs*.  And sure, threading races behave different on different operating systems, they are highly timing sensitive.

Comment: I most likely isn't. We are having a custom PrintMonitor and the AddMonitor gives "Error 127: the specified procedure could not be found" on Win2k and with every attempt. This does not happen on XP and above, so I would think that this is due to unsupported functions. But as it seems it is not only the EnterCriticalSection, but other functions as well. I have spotted some of them with depends.exe. But I still do not get a compile error.

According to MSDN, EnterCriticalSection starts with XP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Well, error 127 is unequivocal.  It isn't EnterCriticalSection nor AddMonitor, they go all the way back to Windows NT 3.1.  Microsoft is removing docs for operating systems they no longer support.  2000 went dead quite a while ago.  Anything relating to printers is indeed likely to cause this kind of problem, there's been lots of flux in the api for them.  Also don't discount the possibility that the machine is just messed up.

Comment: The machine is a freshly installed VM, so this should be fine. You said it's unequivocal, but don't you mean the opposite? Or is there a distinct source for that?

Comment: Sorry for the high frequency of posts... As you said that the functions existed in Win NT 3, I looked into depends again and found the WTSQueryUserToken, which definitely did not exist then. So thank you very much for your help :)

I still don't know why the compile does not warn me about this.

Comment: MSDN often lists XP as baseline because that's their base supported os but in fact lots of apis that are documented as being min level xp have been around since forever. You need an old version of msdn.

Answer (score 1):

I would get a Windows 2000 installation, perhaps in a VM. And then I'd run Dependency Viewer and load the DLL. This will give you a list of the missing API functions.

The problems may well run deeper than this though. Even if the troublesome DLL is using an API function that exists in Windows 2000, it may be using specific functionality of that API function that are only available in later versions of Windows. You may very well need to study this at the source code level.

Comment: Ah, you pushed me in the right direction. I had the Dependency Walker on my Developer System, not in the windows 2000 VM. I will have a look there. Of course, we will have to further look into it at the source code level, but I want to get a first overview, as Win2k users got an error that a procedure is not known, there must be something fundamental.